# error while running terraforrm plan "Inappropriate value for attribute "instance_id": string required."

Tags: terraform

#getting below error while running "terraform plan". i am trying to create three windows compute resources. the instance_name are of list type and a count is added to resource

Error: Incorrect attribute value type

on datasource.tf line 7, in data "oci_core_instance_credentials" "instance_credentials":
7:   instance_id = ["${oci_core_instance.jde_instance.*.id}"]

Inappropriate value for attribute "instance_id": string required.

Answer (score 0):

[oci_core_instance_credentials](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/oci/latest/docs/data-sources/core_instance_credentials) requires just one value. But you are passing an array.

It should be as below assuming that `oci_core_instance.jde_instance` is an array. This way you are using first instance in the array:

```
instance_id = oci_core_instance.jde_instance[0].id
```

If its a single array it should be:

```
instance_id = oci_core_instance.jde_instance.id
```